# Is it correct to put Q.all inside a Q.all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

My code is like the following:

```
let tasks = [];
tasks.push(MyModel.update({ _id: 50 }, { Test: 5000 }).exec());
return Q.all([
   myPromise,
   Q.all(dbTasks)
]);
```

Is it correct to put Q.all inside a Q.all? Will the promises inside `dbTasks` be resolved exactly after `myPromise`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it correct to put Q.all inside a Q.all?

Yes,that should be fine. `Q.all` takes an array of promises an non-promises, and `Q.all` returns a promise. So you're good to go. The resolution value will be a length-2 array with the resolved value of `myPromise` and the resolved values of `dbTasks`.

> Will the promises inside dbTasks be resolved exactly after myPromise?

They will be resolved whenever they resolve. `Q.all` has no control over that.

The promise produced by the outer `Q.all` will resolve when both `myPromise` and all of the promises in `dbTasks` have resolved, or it will reject as soon as any of these promises rejects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread element to expand the inner array into the outer array

```
Promise.all([myPromise, ...dbTasks])
```

Comment: Yes, you can pass `Promise.all()` as an argument to `Promise.all()` and the outer `Promise.all()` will await the iterable within the inner `Promise.all()`. Is the expected result an array having a `Promise` value as first index and and array of values for the remaining indexes of the returned array `[<Promise value>, [<Promise value>, <Promise value>]]` or an array containing no arrays and only `Promise` values  `[<Promise value>, <Promise value>, <Promise value>]` ?